# How to calculate the total time an activity has been on screen?

Tags: android, android-emulator

How would I calculate the total time an activity has been displayed on the screen?  It should be the total time it had been on screen, across its various launches, since it has been installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep a static `time` variable. Start a new timer every time your activity is on screen, that is when onResume is called. And suspend the timer when your activity goes out of screen, that is onPause, onStop, onDestroy and add the time elapsed to the `time` variable.

Copa's answer will be very useful to count the time through many sessions of your application.

Comment: Your answer is perhaps a bit misguiding. Based on it one might think that you could/should do something like this `new Timer().start();`. Obviously, that is not possible as the class `Timer` is for scheduling `TimerTask` objects to be executed at certain time or periodically. So I guess by timer you simply mean that in `onResume` one should put something like this `this.startedAt = SystemColck.elapsedRealtime();` and in `onPause`, `onStop` and `onDestroy` one puts something like this: `if (this.startedAt != null) { static_timer += SystemColck.elapsedRealtime(); this.startedAt = null; }`

Comment: @Timo Lehto, I didn't mean to give any technical details _ just an idea how to do this. But I think your comment is very useful )))

Answer (score 1):

Use the activity lifecircle callback functions to detect what happend to your activity:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

The information how long an activity lived can be stored using the SharedPreferences:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html